# Connect ESX server different Vlan VMs via same Switch port on cisco switch

Tags: vmware, cisco, esx, vlan, cucm

I have a Dell T110II server running ESXi 5.5 and i have 2 VMs which is a Windows 2008 server and Cisco CUCM 8.6.

Windows server in a Vlan 21 and CUCM in a Vlan 10. ESX server connected to Cisco 2960 24 port PoE switch port Gig 0/7 and that switch connected to our L3 Core Switch which is basically doing all the routing.

My problem is i have to contact both Vlan 21 and Vlan 10 VMs via Gig0/7 port. I tried configure that port as trunk but it didn't work.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Cisco switchport needs to be set to mode trunk and dot1q encapsulation. In the vswitch configuration, you create port groups and assign the vlan ID to the port group. You'll bind the network adapters in your virtual machines to these port groups.

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004074

Comment: I checked that link already, since i am not a vmware expert i could not understand the steps!!!

Comment: It tells you step by step. You need to verify the cisco configuration feeding your pNIC. You'll need to check the properties of that vSwitch and make sure it's bound to that pNIC. Create port groups in there and assign the VLAN ID to that port group. Perhaps this video might help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBIYLJK940A

Comment: Thanks! I think i can crack this.